# Cordova Inapp browser reopens on android back button?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I use an 3rd-party Oauth page in an in-app browser to login into my application. On successful login, I close the in-app browser using its close method and move to my home screen. But on Android back button press, it moves back to the in-app browser login page. I'm using Cordova's exit method to quit the app on the back button pressed event. But somewhere I read that I should avoid using the exit method, as it is not a good practice. Can't I close the in-app browser forever to avoid using the exit method to quit my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're handling the `backbutton` cordova [event](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#backbutton). Instead of exiting the app, why not just disable navigation back to that page. On back button event check the route you're going to and if its that page disable it.

Comment: Thanks @john. This will work for me but i won't be able to close my app and have to kill it or minimize it to back ground every time i use the app. if i will be able to close the inapp browser once and forever after my login, then this won't be necessary i guess.